# How to align a paragraph with a textfield

Tags: html, css, text, alignment, paragraph

In a table I have a situation like this:

```
<td> 
<p>1</p>
<p class="obj_2 view"></p><input class="obj_2 modifica" type="text" value=""/>
```

The textfield  appear when I press a button, but the problem is an other one. The textfield appear under the paragraph, but I want it in the same line. So, should I add some Css code or what?

Comment: inside <td>....</td> tag?

Comment: Put the text field in the paragraph.

Comment: @Naveen Oh my God, no! Use display: inline-block or float but don't, never and ever, use tables for layout issues.

Comment: @AurelioDeRosa You're quoting that wrong. The actual quote is "dont ever use tables for layout purposes ___only___". Big difference. And why are you only sweraring at Naveen? You should swear at user2556079 as well, because there's also a table in the question.

Comment: @MrLister That "layout issues" was supposed to be there exactly for specifying the difference from layout questions and data presentation questions.

Comment: @user2556079 Do those paragraphs actually need to be paragraphs? I mean, if you don't want them to be blocks, why use block elements for them in the first place? Can you use spans?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<td> 
  <p style="float:left">1</p>
  <p style="float:left" class="obj_2 view"></p>
  <input style="margin-top:15px;" class="obj_2 modifica" type="text" value=""/>
</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `float:left` property for align 2 p elements in a single line

Answer (score 0):

```
<td>
<p style="float:left;">1<p>
<input type="text" value="" style="float:right;"/>
```

I have ommited the `<p class="obj_2 view"></p>`

Comment: I have a vague feeling that the `.obj_2_view` would have been used for some vague purpose later.